# How to accept any number of more than two digits in Java?

Tags: java

I have to write a program that will accept any number of more than two digits and then display the reverse of that number. How should i write the code for the “accept any number of more than two digits” part?

This is my code:

```
import java.util.Scanner;
public class Reversenum
{
  public static void main(String args [])
    {
        int num, reversenum=0;
        System.out.println(“Input a number and press enter”);
        Scanner in= new Scanner(System.in);
        num= in.nextInt();

        for (;num!=0;)
        {
                reversenum= reversenum*10;
                reversenum= reversenum+num%10;
                num=num/10;
        }
        System.out.println(“Reverse number =“+reversenum);
      }
 }
```

Comment: Your program already _accepts_ any number of more than two digits. Do you want to reject numbers smaller than 10? Or do you need help with reversing numbers greater than 100?

Comment: I'm not sure this helps but... a number with more than two digits is any number greater than 99. Is that cheating?

Comment: Check this out: https://www.programmingsimplified.com/java/source-code/java-program-reverse-number

Answer (score 4):

Do this:

```
public static void main(String args []) {
    int num=0, reversenum=0;
    boolean flag = true;
    while(flag) {
        try {
            System.out.println("Input a number and press enter");
            Scanner in= new Scanner(System.in);
            num= in.nextInt();
            if(num>99) {
                break;
            }else {
                continue;
            }
        }catch (Exception e) {
            continue;
        }

    }

    for (;num!=0;)
    {
            reversenum= reversenum*10;
            reversenum= reversenum+num%10;
            num=num/10;
    }
    System.out.println("Reverse number ="+reversenum);
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

this will ask the user to enter a number with more than 2 digits until it has received the number

```
do {
    System.out.println(“Input a number and press enter”);
    num= in.nextInt();
} while(num < 100);
```

add this where you get your input number